# Azure Speech To Text - Extract Phonemes from spoken words

Tags: c#, .net, azure, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm trying to create a tool using Azure Text-To-Speech that will be sure to pronounce a user's name correctly when speaking the text provided.

The way I figured to do this is by:

1. Having the user speak their name within the context of a few sentences
2. Having Azure extract the Phonemes of the name, specifically, from those spoken words
3. Add those extracted Phonemes back into the SSML for the text-to-speech portion later on

Looking at the docs, it seems the only place Azure gives you back Phonemes is via the `PronunciationAssessmentResult` class. So, I wrote the following code to try and extract it:

```
using (var recognizer = new Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechRecognizer(config))
{
    var proununciationAssessmentConfig = new PronunciationAssessmentConfig(requestedStatement);
    proununciationAssessmentConfig.ApplyTo(recognizer);

    var reply = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();

    var result = PronunciationAssessmentResult.FromResult(reply);

    foreach (var word in result.Words)
    {
        // Here I can add in code to look at word.Word / word.Phonemes
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having here is that it seems the `PronunciationAssessmentResult.FromResult(reply)` returns back the Phonemes Azure, itself, creates from the statement provided, **NOT the ones extracted from the spoken words**.
(In other words, it will create the Phonemes it **expects**, then grades the spoken words for how close the pronunciation is to those Phonemes) - Which is not what I'm looking to do here.

I did find a workaround using `System.Speech.Recognition` (based upon answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20770593/1693085) to a question posed in 2013), but, then, I am limited to only Windows machines as well as (I'm assuming here), a less accurate speech engine than the ones currently out there.

Is there a way to do this using either Azure / Google / some other well-developed speech engine?

ANY sample code would really be helpful!

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55709486/how-to-use-phonetic-or-phoneme-pronunciation-in-google-text-to-speech

Comment: @nikasha, thanks, but, unfortunately, that is the opposite direction of what I need. I'm looking to be able to input spoken speech and have the system break it down into its phonemes. Thanks so much, though.